# IIS Aplication Pool not When The Server is Turn On?

Tags: iis, iis-6

Hi i have a problem with one server, and the problem is that the server iis does not start automatically one of the app pools that we have for one of our applications, but if you go to the iis and make right click on the app pool and click start the app pools starts fine.

Any Idea

Jean

Answer (score 1):

See if the App Pool is set to autostart:

```
adsutil.vbs get w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/AppPoolAutostart
```

Chnage DefaultAppPool to your app pool name.

To set it to auto start, use

```
adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/AppPoolAutostart true
```

Answer (score 0):

Does you application in the AppPool depend on other services (eg SQL) that might still be starting?

I recall Skype used to hijack my port 80 as IIS took too long to start.

Comment: Yes, the application use sql server services.

Comment: So in the services config, set IIS to depend on SQL.